# Обработка GEOJSON на Qt

Tags: qt, geojson

Необходимо из файл формата GEOJSON загружать данные из каждой строки в новый объект класса.

Пример GEOJSON файла:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features" :[ 
{"type":"feature","properties":{"type":"126"},"geometry":
{"type":"POINT","coordinates":[197,98]}}
{"type":"feature","properties":{"type":"126"},"geometry":
{"type":"POINT","coordinates":[142,24]}}
{"type":"feature","properties":{"type":"126"},"geometry":
{"type":"POINT","coordinates":[185,53]}}]}
```

Как извлечь информацию из каждой строки и заполнить поля класса:

```
class Json
{
public:
    Json();
    QString type;
    QString propeties_type;
    QString geometry_type;
    int x_coord,y_coord;
};
```

Пробовал сохранять данные в QVariant, но что делать дальше непонятно

```
QByteArray data = file.readAll();
QJsonDocument jsdoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);
QVariant variant = jsdoc.object()["features"].toVariant();
```

Answer (score 3):

Qt не может просто так преобразовать поля JSON в поля класса. Вам нужно сначала извлечь корневой элемент документа:

```
QJsonObject obj = jsdoc.object();
```

После этого с помощью метода `value` вы можете извлечь конкретное значение по ключу. Его нужно будет преобразовать в нужный тип.

```
QJsonValue value = obj.value("type");
QString t = value.toString(); //FeatureCollection
```

Если вам нужно работать с массивами, используйте метод toArray:

```
QJsonValue value = obj.value("features");
QJsonArray ar = value.toArray();
```

Каждый элемент в этом массиве нужно преобразовывать в нужный вам тип и дальше использовать как вам нужно.

Посмотрите [полный обзор классов JSON в Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html) и  [пример сохранения игры](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html).